# one Collapsible should open at one time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

// Here in my code there are three Collapsibles, after clicking one it will expand, but to close it again i have to click on that particular text.
I would like to make a change: if any of the three Collapsibles are already open, and I click the new button, then the existing Collapsibles should close automatically.

```
 {isSimUAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ simUpgrade: !this.state.simUpgrade });
                  }}>
                    <RegularText text="SIM Upgrade" textColor={this.state.simUpgrade?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.simUpgrade?'bold':'normal'}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Collapsible collapsed={!this.state.simUpgrade}>
                    <Button
                      block
                      primary
                      onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'swap',1)}
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    >
                      <Text>Proceed</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Collapsible>
                </View>}
                {isSimCAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ lostSim: !this.state.lostSim });
                  }}>
                     <RegularText text="SIM Change" textColor={this.state.lostSim?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.lostSim?'bold':'normal'}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Collapsible collapsed={!this.state.lostSim}>
                    <Button
                      block
                      primary
                      onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'lost',1)}
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    >
                      <Text>Proceed</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Collapsible>
                </View>}
                {isSimEAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ validator: !this.state.validator });
                  }}>
                   <RegularText text="E-validator" textColor={this.state.validator?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.validator?'bold':'normal'}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Collapsible collapsed={!this.state.validator}>
                    <Button
                      block
                      primary
                      onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'validate',0)}
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    >
                      <Text>Proceed</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Collapsible>
                </View>}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use one common property for state instead of three different property, that single property can have different values in your case it can have 'simUpgrade', 'lostSim' and 'validator' i.e

```
this.state = {
    active : 'simUpgrade' 
  }
```

And than in your code you can use it like this

```
{isSimUAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
       this.setState({ active: 'simUpgrade' });
      }}>
         <RegularText text="SIM Upgrade" textColor={this.state.simUpgrade?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.simUpgrade?'bold':'normal'}}/>
         </TouchableOpacity>
             <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.active !== 'simUpgrade'}>
             <Button
              block
              primary
              onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'swap',1)}
              style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
              >
              <Text>Proceed</Text>
             </Button>
          </Collapsible>
          </View>}
     {isSimCAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
       this.setState({ active: 'lostSim'});
      }}>
        <RegularText text="SIM Change" textColor={this.state.lostSim?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.lostSim?'bold':'normal'}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.active !== 'lostSim'}>
        <Button
         block
         primary
         onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'lost',1)}
         style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
         >
         <Text>Proceed</Text>
         </Button>
         </Collapsible>
         </View>}
                {isSimEAllowed && <View style={styles.paymentMethod}>
                  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({ active: 'validator' });
                  }}>
                   <RegularText text="E-validator" textColor={this.state.validator?'#006288':'black'} style={{fontWeight:this.state.validator?'bold':'normal'}}/>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                  <Collapsible collapsed={this.state.active !== 'validator'}>
                    <Button
                      block
                      primary
                      onPress={() => this.loadScreen('CustomerVerification', 'validate',0)}
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    >
                      <Text>Proceed</Text>
                    </Button>
                  </Collapsible>
                </View>}
```